# bzip2 and compressed stream concatenation

Tags: gzip, compression

With gzip you can do something like this:

```
gzip -c file1 > output.gz
gzip -c file2 >> output.gz
gzip -c file3 >> output.gz
```

and when you uncompress output.gz it will contain concatenated values of file1 file2 and file3.

Can the same be done reliably with bzip2? I can't find any mention of this in bzip2 docs, but maybe I'm just bad at reading/understanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bzip2` apparently works the same way as `gzip` for that operation, even using the same `-c` option. From the `bzip2` man page:

```
       bunzip2 will correctly decompress a file which is the concatenation  of
       two  or  more compressed files.  The result is the concatenation of the
       corresponding uncompressed files.  Integrity testing (-t)  of  concate‐
       nated compressed files is also supported.
```